# How can I join two tables in Google Sheets to output all combinations without including blanks?

Tags: google-sheets, join, google-sheets-formula

I have been trying to combine two tables by modifying formulas similar to my situation, but have not been able to achieve the desired result. I am generating two tables that both contain blanks, and want to combine them without including blank results. Here is an example of how my tables are structured and the final result I'm looking for:

Table 1:

| Company | Geography |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | US |
| Apple | Canada |
| Apple |  |
| Apple |  |
| Samsung | US |
| Samsung | South Korea |
| Samsung |  |
| Samsung |  |
| Samsung |  |

Table 2:

| Company | Product |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | Cell Phone |
| Apple |  |
| Apple | Laptop |
| Samsung | Cell Phone |
| Samsung | TV |
| Samsung | Laptop |
| Samsung |  |
| Samsung |  |

Final Result:

| Company | Geography | Product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | US | Cell Phone |
| Apple | US | Laptop |
| Apple | Canada | Cell Phone |
| Apple | Canada | Laptop |
| Samsung | US | Cell Phone |
| Samsung | US | TV |
| Samsung | US | Laptop |
| Samsung | South Korea | Cell Phone |
| Samsung | South Korea | TV |
| Samsung | South Korea | Laptop |

Would really appreciate specific formulas for how to accomplish this as I have had no luck in my many attempts! The two tables are on the same sheet, and I would like the final table to output on that sheet as well if possible.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18QLt7QyGV5mTOaq3j6j-N0AhRG_nvzUMofGb88KWdFA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: open access to your spreadsheet

Comment: sheet is private

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=INDEX(SORT(QUERY(TRIM(SPLIT(
 FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(FILTER({A2:A&"×", B2:B}, B2:B<>"")),,9^9)&"×"&
 FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(FILTER({D2:D&"×", E2:E}, E2:E<>"")),,9^9))), "×")), 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col4 where Col1=Col3", 0), 1, 1, 2, 0, 3, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I have been going crazy trying to get it and this worked perfectly